# How do I generate new vectors based on the results of ifelse statements in r?

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate two new variables based on the values of an extant variable. It's a very simple operation but I can't seem to get it to function correctly and on all values of a vector in r. I'm trying to convert to r from SPSS but this particular goal does not seem to translate very well into r.

For every value of Condition, I want to generate a value for a new variable called "expect." So (informally) I want something like

```
if Condition = 1, expect = 0
if Condition = 2, expect = 1
if Condition = 3, expect = 0
if Condition = 4, expect = 1
```

How do I put this into r code? How do I run these chained ifelse statements on entire vectors? I realise this is a very beginner question but I've been looking for quite some time and have not found a solution. The best I've been able to glean is:

```
expect<-ifelse(Condition == 1, 0, 1, ifelse(Condition == 2, 1, 0, ifelse(Condition == 3, 0, 1, ifelse(Condition == 4, 1, 0))))
```

But I know that's not correct.

If anyone can help, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not do two at a time: `ifelse(Condition==1 | Condition==3, 0, 1)` assuming there are only 4 possible values.

Comment: The `ifelse` function takes the following three values: `condition, yes, no`. However, your code has the following: `condition, yes, no, ifelse...`. Replace the `no` with the next `ifelse` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

create a map between old and new values, `map = c(0, 1, 0, 1)` and then subset `expect = map[Condition]`. Use names for character-based mapping, `map = c(foo=1, bar=2); unname(map[c("foo", "foo", "bar")])`

Answer (score 0):

You can always play "code golf" and make this more compact, but here's a simple illustration of how to do that:

```
Condition <- c(1,2,3,4,0,3,4,5)
expect    <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)

for(i in 1:length(Condition)){
  if (Condition[i] == 1){expect[i] <- 0}
  if (Condition[i] == 2){expect[i] <- 1}
  if (Condition[i] == 3){expect[i] <- 0}
  if (Condition[i] == 4){expect[i] <- 1}
}

expect
[1]  0  1  0  1 NA  0  1 NA
```